# OpenGL ES Degenerate Triangles With TRIANGLE_FAN?

Tags: android, performance, opengl-es

In OpenGL ES, is it possible to use degenerate triangles (triangles with 0 area) to separate TRIANGLE_FAN objects in a vertex array?  Or is this only possible with TRIANGLE_STRIP?

If the answer is no, what would be the best way to batch multiple TRIANGLE_FAN vertex array draw calls into one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, the answer is no, since all triangle fan triangles share same vertex.

If you want to batch multiple triangle fans it would be better to use [Vertex Buffer Objects](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/VBO#Vertex_Buffer_Object) or VBO's with `GL_TRIANGLES` mode instead. There will be a small index buffer overhead, but it would provide a better flexibility.

Comment: Thank you, this helps.  Also, here's [another link](http://www.learnopengles.com/android-lesson-seven-an-introduction-to-vertex-buffer-objects-vbos/) to VBO information specific to Android / Java OpenGL ES usage with some good examples.

Answer (score 1):

You could also triangulate your surface as a strip instead of a fan. It would allow you to use degenerate triangles and batch your draw calls into one.

If your surface is a n-gon it's easy. Just change the order of vertex creation. Instead of going around the center, pick a vertex to start and generate the others by iterating on both sides. Here is an example with an [Hexagon](http://www.drking.org.uk/hexagons/flexagons/tp6.gif). The left image uses a triangle strip, the middle uses a fan.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: Ah I don't have enough reputation to post comments :(

Comment: Seems like a catch 22, but the best way to get that reputation is to ask good questions, give good answers, and make good edits on problematic texts. You're limited to 200 reputation a day, and bounties and accepted answers are excluded from that limit! ;)

Comment: So the thing to do here would be to elaborate on your answer so that it's not deleted, and then try to answer more questions. Good luck.